# Using NSLog to print navigationType

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the following paragraph:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType *)navigationType {
    NSURL * url = [request URL];
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"loggedout" options:(NSRegularExpressionOptions)NSCaseInsensitiveSearch error:NULL];
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [urlString length])];    
    [regex release];
    if (numberOfMatches > 0) {
//        NSLog(@"%@", url);
//        NSLog(@"%i", numberOfMatches);
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
        return NO;
    }
    if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I would like to print the "navigationType" variable with NSLog, but I am unable to find a format specifier (e.g.: @"%@" or @"%d") that is compatible with the variable or does not cause the app to crash. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSLog(@"NavigationType: %i", navigationType);`

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` is typedef on `NSUInteger`.
Use `%lu` format specifier to print out the value.